# How do I add more members to my ENUM-type column in MySQL for a table size of more than 40 million rows?

Tags: mysql, enums, rds, alter, amazon-aurora

I have a table size of 40 million rows and I wish to modify an enum column of a table an Aurora MySQL RDS Database V5.6.10 to add more. This table is a frequently updated one. Has anyone ever tried altering such tables before? If so, can you please elaborate on the experience?

Table Structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tee_sizes` (
id bigint auto_increment,
customer_id bigint,
tee-size enum('small', 'large', 'x-large'),
created_at  timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
updated_at  timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36910751 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I wish to add 'xx-large' to the column tee-size.

Will there be a downtime while doing this?

Comment: Now you found out that using `ENUM` datatype in MySQL is bad, learn from this and use a type table and a `type_id` in your table next time and stop using `ENUM` datatype.. Then you don't have to use a `ALTER TABLE` command and most likely have downtime on this table unless InnoDB online DDL can do it's work.. Besides can you add table structure? `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` and MySQL version `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: Thanks for the comment @RaymondNijland. I have updated the table structure and version above

Comment: "I have updated the table structure" we need a complete `CREATE TABLE ...` statement output which   `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` generates for you, replace `<table>` with your tablename.

Comment: Also, using '-' in table/column idenitifiers is fantastically dangerous.

Comment: Noted! @Strawberry :)

Comment: @RaymondNijland, I've added the complete table structure.

Comment: i've posted a possible answer to try out..

Comment: `ENUM` is not _bad_ - it has its use cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL 5.6 should allow [InnoDB online DDL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl.html) **without** anny downtime on that table and concurrent queries should still work on that table while altering.

```
   ALTER TABLE tee_sizes MODIFY COLUMN `tee-size` enum('small', 'large', 'x-large', 'new-item'),
   ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE;
```

`ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE` would force MySQL in executing in the
requested level of concurrency **without** downtime. 
If your MySQL version does not execute then the requested level of concurrency was not available meaning  `ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE` needs to be changed.

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cwodtjpmjKBpkZspRJBUpM/3)

**Edited because of comment:**

> Wait.. So, does this force any locks? ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE
>   would force MySQL in executing (if allowed) without downtime if your
>   MySQL does not execute it means it can't be done using
>   ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE This statement is confusing.

No it does not lock copy/paste from the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl.html)

> You can control aspects of a DDL operation using the ALGORITHM and
>   LOCK clauses of the ALTER TABLE statement. These clauses are placed at
>   the end of the statement, separated from the table and column
>   specifications by commas. .. **To avoid accidentally making the table
>   unavailable for reads, writes, or both, specify a clause on the ALTER
>   TABLE statement such as LOCK=NONE` (permit reads and writes)** or
>   LOCK=SHARED (permit reads). **The operation halts immediately if the
>   requested level of concurrency is not available.**

Comment: This contradicts your comment somewhat.

Comment: Wait.. So, does this force any locks? 

`ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE would force MySQL in executing (if allowed) without downtime if your MySQL does not execute it means it can't be done using ALGORITHM=INPLACE, LOCK=NONE` This statement is confusing.

Comment: @SathyasarathiGunasekaran i've updated mine answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland

For someone who is about to try this out; few pointers:
The above command works and please be aware that this will take longer to complete, yet it's pretty safe to execute.
For about 41 Million rows, it took about 52 minutes on an 8 core cluster

Comment: "The above command works and please be aware that this will take longer to complete" @SathyasarathiGunasekaran iam pretty when MySQL didn't used `ALGORITHM=INPLACE` more time would have been lost because of the disk copy which is needed to `ALTER` the table

Comment: Using mysql 8.0.19 I tried an INPLACE modify of an existing ENUM field and it told me I have to use copy. (that's 2 days downtime for the copy to complete sadly)
So it seems they dropped the support

Comment: Using Mysql 8.0.23 and it worked flawlessly - updated the enum in 1 second. According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-column-operations ("Modifying the definition of an ENUM or SET column"), this operation only modifies metadata.